# Parametro de reverse_lazy en Django

Tags: django

```
class CrearClienti(CreateView):
    template_name = 'clienti.html'
    form_class = RegCliModelForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('clienti:crear_clienti')
```

Me da este error

**'clienti' is not a registered namespace**

Estoy intentando trabajar con modales: esta es la url

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <a onclick="return abrir_modal('{% url 'clienti:crear_clienti' %}')" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</a>
</div>
```

Adición:
este es mi código en urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),   
url(r'^clienti/$', ListadoClienti.as_view(), name="Listado_Clienti"),
url(r'^nuevo/$', CrearClienti.as_view(), name="crear_Clienti"),
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Has añadido el urls.py de clienti en la urls.py de la aplicación? Si es posible añade el código de urls.py de la aplicación y del clienti

Comment: Puedes añadir tu(s) archivo(s) de urls en la publicación?

Comment: Añadí el urls.py muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error se debe a que en efecto no tienes definido un `namespace` llamado `clienti`

Bastaría con que utilizaras el `reverse_lazy` solo con el nombre de la url que estas definiendo en tu archivo de urls de esta forma

`success_url = reverse_lazy('crear_Clienti')`

Donde `crear_Clienti` es el nombre que has definido para la url en tu `urls.py`

Comment: Excelente Angel, muchas gracias. :) Solucionado

Comment: Por nada @Vacanito si la respuesta te fue útil y es correcta, por favor no dudes en marcarla como la respuesta correcta